# 3 countries name into 1 country name

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

Bellow I operate three countries name into a country name.
The 4 countries must have different names
Determine how the operation works, then replace ?? with a country name.

**Example**
 1. Iceland # Haiti & Trinidad And Tobago = Chile
 2. Austria # Benin & Uzbekistan = Iran
 3. Austria # Somalia & Uni Arab Emirates = Laos
 4. Denmark # China & Turkmenistan = Chad
 5. Bhutan # Angola & Lithuania = Gabon

**Questions**
 1. Iceland # Iran & China = ??
 2. Canada # Lithuania & Nicaragua = ??
 3. Austria # Slovenia & Elsavador = ??
 4. Slovenia # Greece & Cote D Ivoire = ??
 5. Canada # Mongolia & Macedonia = ??
 6. Mauritius # Tanzania & Uzbekistan = ??
 7. Germany # Romania & Singapore = ??
 8. Germany # USA & Timor Leste = ??
 9. Lithuania # Canada & Nicaragua = ??
 10. Algeria # Sudan & Israel = ??
 11. Austria # Malawi & Zimbabwe = ??
 12. Mauritania # USA & Canada = ??
 13. Thailand # Ukraine & Denmark = ??
 14. Indonesia # Jamaica & Tajikistan = ??
 15. North Korea # USA & Iran = ??
 16. Estonia # India & Italy = ??
 17. Australia # Congo & Lesotho = ??
 18. Armenia # Australia & Elsavador = ??
 19. Estonia # Nepal & Jordan = ??
 20. Honduras # Tunisia & Nigeria = ??

**Bonus puzzle**
Find another 3 countries name to form 1 country name

Comment: "Uni" or "United"? "Cote D Ivoire" or "Cote d'Ivoire"?

Comment: @jonathan : I use some abreviatons, at my puzzle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the meanings of the operators:

> The operation X # Y means concatenate X+Y into XY.
>  *AUSTRIA # BENIN = AUSTRIABENIN*
>  
>  The operation X & Y means that, for each letter occurrence in Y, remove one occurrence of that letter from X if possible.
>  *AUSTRIABENIN & UZBEKISTAN = RAIN*
>  
>  The operation X = Y means that Y is an anagram of X.
>  *RAIN = IRAN*

Solved Questions

> 1. Iceland # Iran & China = **Ireland**
>  2. Canada # Lithuania & Nicaragua = **Thailand**
>  3. Austria # Slovenia & Elsavador = **Tunisia**
>  4. Slovenia # Greece & Cote D Ivoire = **Senegal**
>  5. Canada # Mongolia & Macedonia = **Angola**
>  6. Mauritius # Tanzania & Uzbekistan = **Mauritania**
>  7. Germany # Romania & Singapore = **Myanmar**
>  8. Germany # USA & Timor Leste = **Guyana**
>  9. Lithuania # Canada & Nicaragua = **Thailand**
>  10. Algeria # Sudan & Israel = **Uganda**
>  11. Austria # Malawi & Zimbabwe = **Australia**
>  12. Mauritania # USA & Canada = **Mauritius**
>  13. Thailand # Ukraine & Denmark = **Lithuania**
>  14. Indonesia # Jamaica & Tajikistan = **Macedonia**
>  15. North Korea # USA & Iran = **South Korea**
>  16. Estonia # India & Italy = **Indonesia**
>  17. Australia # Congo & Lesotho = **Nicaragua**
>  18. Armenia # Australia & Elsavador = **Mauritania**
>  19. Estonia # Nepal & Jordan = **Palestine**
>  20. Honduras # Tunisia & Nigeria = **South Sudan**

Bonus

> Tonga # Laos & Sri Lanka = Togo
>  Russia # Nepal & Belarus = Spain (<- credit to [Jonathan Allan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16717/jonathan-allan))

Comment: looks good to me :)

Comment: (submitted comment by mistake before I double checked, now double checked) I have an answer for the bonus if you want it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Got my own, although I'm sure there are many possibilities.

Comment: I added it to the Bonus section. Assuming you have edit permissions, if you come up with others, feel free to add them too.